# How can i transfer a column value to my managed bean?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable

I am using a datatable in JSF:

```
<h:dataTable  var="dataItem" value="#{operationsBean.creneauxMedecin}" border="1">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Rendez-vous de #{operationsBean.medecin.titre} #{operationsBean.medecin.prenom} #{operationsBean.medecin.nom} le #{operationsBean.txtJour}"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Créneau horaire"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText id="id" value="#{dataItem.hdebut}h#{dataItem.mdebut}-#{dataItem.hfin}h#{dataItem.mfin}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Client"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{operationsBean.clt }"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

Please how can i transfer a column's(((dataItem.id))) value to my managed bean ?
N.B dataItem is a datatable row that contains(id,version,hdebut,mdebut....)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an action listener method in your managed bean and call that via a command link and pass a param as part of the tag, if you google you can see many examples.

```
<h:commandLink value="click me" actionListener="#{managedbean.actionListenerMethod}">
  <f:param name="paramInternalId" value="#{dataTableIter.id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaqd.html#bnaqj

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i dont want a commandLink on my JSF page, all i can display on my page is the columns of my datatable. Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: I created a private dataItem attribut in my managed bean with its getter and setter, while testing it in my bean it seems not empty but when i try to do dataItem.getId() it generates a java.lang.NullPointerException